# Why web Scraping with Python gives me an error?

Tags: python, web-scraping

In my code i simply want to check the prize of one article in Unieuro online store, a famous store in italy. But even if i used the User-Agent for allow my connection the program works only sometimes, right now i'm trying and it gives me always this error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

How to solve this? Please help me, here is the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
try:
    url = 'https://www.unieuro.it/online/Giochi-Playstation-5/The-Last-of-Us-Parte-I-pidSON9405597' #Unieuro
    headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
    pagina = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(pagina.content,'html.parser')
    prezzo = soup.find(id='features').get_text()
    prezzo = prezzo.split('Iva Inclusa')[0]
    if prezzo.count('%'):
        prezzo = prezzo.split('%')[-1]
        prezzo = prezzo.strip()
        prezzo = prezzo[0:7]
        print(prezzo)   #fine the last Unieuro
        # manda email del prezzo scontato
    else:
        print('Prezzo non scontato fratellì')
        # manda email prezzo non scontato (80,99 €) Unieuro
except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
    print('Errore fratè')
```

Comment: when I try to visit that url in browser, I get `ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` from chrome. does the site actually exist/work for you regularly?

Comment: If the server doesn't like you, we can't change its opinion.

Comment: what information do you expect to receive?

Comment: @TZHX Mhh it's strange because this morning when i refreshed the page it gives an error even to me similar to your error, but now if i run the program it works and gives me the prize i'm looking for, it seems that the connection to the url works only sometimes, if you try now the url works for you?

Comment: @SergeyK the price of the article, it seems that the connection to the url works only sometimes because this morning when i refreshed the page it gives me an error sometimes, what it could be?

Answer (score 0):

The fact that the server does not return the page can be due to a lot of things, for example, your Internet provider, website provider, heavy channel load, temporary blocking, etc.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.unieuro.it/online/Giochi-Playstation-5/The-Last-of-Us-Parte-I-pidSON9405597"
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
current_price = soup.find('div', class_='pdp-right__price').get_text(strip=True)
original_price = soup.find('span', class_='original-price').get_text(strip=True)
print(current_price, '\u0336'.join(original_price))
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
€64,00 €̶8̶0̶,̶9̶9
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer, i runned the code a lot fo times making small adjustments today, maybe receiving a lot of requests the url Unieuro (it's an online store) blocked me for the too many requests? Is it possibile? Because before refreshing the page it says that the site redirected me too many times, but reopening the site i think refreshed the system and the program works for now, maybe i don't have to send too many requests in a short period of time, i know it's complicated to explain i apologize

Comment: @Forty966996 u can prevent your IP address from being banned by using a proxy in your code. You can find a proxies on the Internet or use a vpn. I didn't encounter the site being unavailable, although I sent 100 requests in a row for the test